# Middleware laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel and I have one problem with middleware. On official laravel site, I found code for creating controller.

When I creating controller it is recommended  to add middleware in constructor or this is only if I need some additional functionalities?

Also, if I include auth middleware, did I get some benefits by default, like security checks or similar or I must to rewrite middleware code first?

```
class UserController extends Controller {
/**
 * Instantiate a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
  public function __construct() {  
    **//this part includes some protection or similar by default ?**  
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it really depends on what you want it to do. Please elaborate.

Comment: Middleware is basically if you want to protect your routes, for instance the middleware you are using `auth` would redirect a guest user ( a user who is logged out) to the login page.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I understand good I have this posibilitty automatically, already written in laravel ? Do I need to include this part of code when I creating controller or not ?

Answer (score 1):

[Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware) is used when you want to filter the `HTTP` requests entering your application.

For example, including the built-in `auth` middleware will restrict non-authenticated users from accessing a page and redirect them to the login screen.

You can include middleware into your controller and routes.

In the controller you do it like so:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

For a route you do this:

```
Route::get('/page', 'MyController@myMethod')->middleware('auth');
```

---

> Do I need to include this part of code when I creating controller or not ?

As I said in my comment, it really depends on the desired functionality whether you use it or not.

**An example**

Your homepage should probably be accessible for anyone who visits you website, while your dashboard should only be displayed to authenticated users.

That's where you would include the auth middleware.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I need to include middleware in Controller constructor and in my route also ?

Comment: One of them is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Question #1**

Do you need to use `$this->middleware('auth');` in your controller?

**Answer:**   Only if you want to protect all of the methods of that controller from non-authenticated users and only allow signed in users to access controller actions.

**Question #2**

Do you get benefits for using the `auth` middleware?

**Answer:**   Yes you do, only authenticated users can access the controller or routes protected by `auth`.

** Question #3**

Do you need to write your own middleware?

**Answer:** Only if you need to override a middleware or need extra functionality that is not already provided (`php artisan make:auth`), but if you are rolling your own login functionality then you will likely need/want to create your own middleware.

**Resources:**

Look in `App\Http\Kernel.php` and you will see that the `$routeMiddleware` array matches the `auth` middleware to the `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class` which actually verifies that the current user is logged in and allows them to pass, if they are not logged in then it will redirect them to the '/login' route.

You will see that Laravel uses quite a bit of middleware by default, such as starting the session, encrypting cookies and protecting against CSRF forgery.

There are several ways to implement middleware, which I'm sure you saw in the docs.

**Some Helpful Video Tutorials:**

I suggest you watch each of the free series usually titled `Laravel from Scratch` on `Laracasts.com`. I would also suggest watching all of from Laravel 5.7 back to 5.1 or 5.0 as Jeffrey Way may use different techniques in similar situations and it will provide you with a great tips and helpful information as to how things work along with some Laravel best practices along the way. I've subscribed to him for years and work in Laravel everyday and I still learn some new things from watching his videos, a subscription is easily worth 10-20 what he charges.